Deploy artifactory to openshift with PostgreSQL data base config with Dockerfile
I'm trying to run artifactory-oss in openshift with configuration of PostgreSQL database .
I have the following Dockerfile, which I build using kaniko in the GitLab CI/CD pipeline:
FROM docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:latest

ENV ARTIFACTORY_HOME=/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory

VOLUME /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory
VOLUME /data/artifactory

# Handle group creation to avoid errors if the group already exists
RUN groupadd -f artifactory && \
    useradd -g artifactory -d $ARTIFACTORY_HOME -u 999 artifactory || true

RUN mkdir -p $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/{data,logs,backup} && \
    chown -R artifactory: $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/{data,logs,backup}

ADD $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/etc/db.properties .
# Copy custom database configuration to the Artifactory config directory
COPY db.properties $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/etc/db.properties
RUN echo $(ls -1 $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/etc/)
RUN echo $(tail -n 10 $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/etc/db.properties)

# Set PostgreSQL environment variables
ENV DB_TYPE=postgresql
ENV DB_HOST=$DB_HOST
ENV DB_PORT=6601
ENV DB_USER=artifactory
ENV DB_PASSWORD=$ARTIFACTORY_DB_PASSWORD
#ENV DB_NAME=artifactory
ENV VIRTUAL_PORT=443

EXPOSE 8081

USER artifactory

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint-artifactory.sh"]

EXPOSE 8081

The Docekerfile is built and then deployed using the following GitLab CI/CD pipeline:
stages:
- dockerize
- deploy

variables:
  SERVER: $OPENSHIFT_SERVER
  NAMESPACE: hse-artifactory
  
dockerize:
  stage: dockerize
  image:
    name: ${GITLAB_REGISTRY_HOST}/ci-tools/docker-image-builder
    entrypoint: [ "" ]
  variables:
    IMAGE_DESTINATION: ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}/openshift-artifactory-oss:latest
  script:
    # Prepare Kaniko configuration file
    - echo "{\"auths\":{\"$CI_REGISTRY\":{\"username\":\"$CI_REGISTRY_USER\",\"password\":\"$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD\"}}}" > /kaniko/.docker/config.json
    # Build and push the image from the Dockerfile at the root of the project.
    - /kaniko/executor --context $CI_PROJECT_DIR --dockerfile $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile --destination $IMAGE_DESTINATION --build-arg SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=$SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE --build-arg ARTIFACTORY_DB_PASSWORD=$ARTIFACTORY_DB_PASSWORD
    - echo "Image pushed successfully to ${IMAGE_DESTINATION}"
  when: on_success


deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: ${GITLAB_REGISTRY_HOST}/paas-tools/openshift-client:latest
  variables:
    APP_NAME: openshift-artifactory-oss
  script:
    - "oc import-image $APP_NAME --all --server=$SERVER --namespace $NAMESPACE --token=$IMAGE_IMPORT_TOKEN"
    - "sleep 15s && oc rollout status deployment/$APP_NAME --server=$SERVER --namespace $NAMESPACE --token=$IMAGE_IMPORT_TOKEN"
  needs:
    - dockerize
  when: manual

The build is executed successfully in GitLab, then the image is published in GitLab registry and then deployed to the openshift.
When I check the logs of the pod in openshift, I see following message:
Preparing to run Artifactory in Docker
Running as uid=1017250000(1017250000) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),1017250000
Dockerfile for this image can found inside the container.
To view the Dockerfile: 'cat /docker/artifactory-oss/Dockerfile.artifactory'.
Copying Artifactory bootstrap files
2024-07-09T14:51:01.587Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:3553 ] [main] - Mapping value from deprecated key DB_TYPE to new key JF_SHARED_DATABASE_TYPE
2024-07-09T14:51:01.647Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:3553 ] [main] - Mapping value from deprecated key DB_HOST to new key JF_SHARED_DATABASE_HOST
2024-07-09T14:51:01.705Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:3553 ] [main] - Mapping value from deprecated key DB_PORT to new key JF_SHARED_DATABASE_PORT
2024-07-09T14:51:01.794Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:3553 ] [main] - Mapping value from deprecated key DB_USER to new key JF_SHARED_DATABASE_USER
2024-07-09T14:51:02.081Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:1617 ] [main] - Checking open files and processes limits
2024-07-09T14:51:02.106Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:1620 ] [main] - Current max open files is 1048576
2024-07-09T14:51:02.132Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:1631 ] [main] - Current max open processes is 4194304
[WARN ] Error while initializing File resolver : Config file does not exists : /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/system.yaml
Database connection check failed Could not determine database type
2024-07-09T14:51:02.233Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:1700 ] [main] - Testing directory /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var has read/write permissions for user id 1017250000
2024-07-09T14:51:02.261Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:1715 ] [main] - Permissions for /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var are good
...

So looks like data base connection is not configured correctly: Database connection check failed Could not determine database type. According to artifactory documentation, the database configuration is loaded from db.properties file which I copy in Dockerfile file:
COPY db.properties $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/etc/db.properties
However, when I check if db.properties exists in the openshfit pod of deployed artifcatory, I can't find it.
Do you know what is wrong in my Dockerfile/GitLab CI/CD config? Why is my db.properties file not copied to openshift?

In a Kubernetes context, I probably wouldn't try to run this custom image at all.  In particular "baking in" things like database credentials, where on the one hand docker inspect can trivially retrieve them and on the other they're hard to change, isn't usually a best practice.  Can you use Kubernetes Secrets or ConfigMaps to provide these configuration files and environment variables, and inject them into an unmodified image?
